# Modificar el valor de una celda con ajax y php

Tags: php, ajax

Saludos de nuevo mi gente!! tengo una situación y es que he logrado capturar el valor de un  de una tabla con la finalidad de cambiarlo.

El problema es que una vez obtenido el dato cambiado no puedo enviar el nuevo valor a la celda correspondiente, no se si me exprese bien.

```
    function cambiaCantidad(idcantidad){
   $('#cantidadU').val(idcantidad);
   $('#actualizarCantidad').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#cantidadU').focus();
})
    $("input[type=text]").focus(function(){    
    this.select();
    });
}

$('#btnActualizaCantidad').click(function(){
     datos= $('#cantidadU').val();

  //Hasta Aqui todo bien!!

     $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            data:"datos=" + datos,
            url:"tablaVentasTemp.php",
            success:function(r){


               $('#tablaVentasTempLoad').load("inicio/tablaVentasTemp.php");

            }
        });

        });
```

el problema esta que no envía la variable $_POST['datos']; a la URL: tablaVentasTemp.php.

Answer (score 0):

cambiar la estructura de data por data:{datos:datos}

ejemplo:

```
var  datos= $('#cantidadU').val();
$.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            data:{"datos":datos},
            // Formato de datos que se espera en la respuesta
            //dataType: "json",
            url:"tablaVentasTemp.php",
            success:function(r){


               $('#tablaVentasTempLoad').load("inicio/tablaVentasTemp.php");

            }
        });
```

Comment: Hola Juan Carlos, gracias por responder, la pregunta sería como lo recibo en PHP? $datos=$_POST['datos']; //me da este error=Notice: Undefined index: datos in.....